# barplot not showing up properly, numbers mixed up

Tags: plot

[image]

1.Numbers, I am unsure as to whether I am calling it right, are jumbled up.

2.`par("mar") par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))` are lines of code I have typed in.

3. Posted image, rolling a dice many times,is the result.

I have tried to find a similar post but I didn't find one.

If there is anything I could be of help providing more infos, please let me know.

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks,